# Publish Fails when using configsource

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I am trying to publish a mvc app. I am running into the following error whenever I publish

Error   203 An error occurred loading a configuration file: Directory 'C:\DevelopmentPath\csautoparameterize\original\bin\Extensions' does not exist. Failed to start monitoring file changes.

The extensions directory is a directory that contains an external config source file that is contained in a seperate probject that is referenced in this application. It doesn't look like that directory structure is being copied over, and is missing

Comment: what is the build action on the folder?

Comment: looks like it only occurs the second time I try to publish. The first time I get a different error about the publish URL returning a 404

Comment: any news about this issue?

Comment: I know this is an oldie, but have you ever solved this issue? and if you have do you remember how? we're having the exact same thing at this moment